# Should you place accents on letters in academic writing in English?

Tags: writing

Is there a standard practice in academic writing regarding the use of accented letters when the underlying language is English? I'm specifically thinking of the word *naive,* which often has a dieresis above the *i,* but I suppose this is applicable to other words.

I would prefer to not use them since it's simpler and seems somehow less pretentious to me.

Also, is there is a difference between dissertations and journal articles?

Comment: As far as I know, there are many style guides and dictionaries that does not recommend using these accents. Thus, you are free not to use them in whatever you publish yourself and have the copy editor worry about it everywhere else.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: _Many_ style guides and dictionaries that do not recommend using accents?! Can you cite a few of them, please? Moreover, in languages which use accented letters, removing an accent can completely change the meaning of a word: e.g., in French, _à_ is a preposition, but _a_ is a verb. Do you really want to be misunderstood? Or being considered sloppy? By the way, BMS, modern typesetting systems allow you to write accented letters without many difficulties: how many times do you want to write _naïve_ in an academic paper?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Merriam Webster: [naive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naive), [cliche](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cliche), [Gaussian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaussian). Moreöver, this question is explicitly about the English language. I am far from dropping recommending diacritics in other languages (I have once taken some effort to have a Romanian author’s name spelt with ș instead of ş in a citation), I am not even recommending anything regarding English, just reporting.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I'm in physics, and I type Schrodinger often.

Comment: It's perfectly correct in English to just write "naive". But it's good manners to include accents in peoples' names, at least when these people do so on their own papers.

Comment: @BMS: I thought your question was about the English language and not about proper names?

Comment: @BMS: The letter _o_ with umlaut can be replaced by the digraph _oe_, so you can write _Schroedinger_ instead of _Schrodinger_ (see e.g. [this discussion on German.SE](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4992/conversion-table-for-diacritics-e-g-%C3%BC-%E2%86%92-ue)).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: But only if it’s impossible to use *ö,* which, as you correctly remarked earlier, rarely is the case nowadays.

Comment: I am fine with that level of "pretentiousness". I feel using letters beyond the scope of unaccented `a`..`z` in a published document is just as "pretentious" as using capitals in a text message or an instant messenging message. It's not something *extra* that you *add* to stand out, it's something *normal* that you *keep doing*, even though many others might be too lazy.

Comment: How is this question specific to academia? Does it seem *likely* to you that academia would have different standard spellings to any other branch of formal English usage? Why would you spell *naïve* differently in an academic paper to how you'd spell it elsewhere?

Comment: @TRiG: Academia has its own conventions and rules for its proper type of documents, such as papers and other types of publications. Questions about these conventions are fully on-topic. Other types of documents may have different target audiences and goals, so I can imagine that a commercial product description would favour a "flashy, modern" way of spelling that conveys "simplicity" over a "precise" way of spelling that conveys "thoroughness", as it may be found in academic papers.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: While Schroedinger is better than Schrodinger, I'm sure the man would have been very much angered if you used either instead of Schrödinger. There are also cases where different names are possible, like Müller and Mueller, and changing the first one would destroy the distinction.

Comment: I believe *naïve* is more common in the UK, while *naive* is more common in the US.  Asking about "English" may not get you a useful answer.

Comment: Unless you are going to write "naïf" in the masculine case, I don't see the point. "naive" is an English word, "naïve" is a French word; if you write "naïve", you're writing the French word. And if you use it in the masculine case, you've committed a much more egregious error than leaving out a diaeresis.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: The use of diaereses is hardly unique to French; English uses the same mark for the same purpose in words like "cöoperation" and "cöop".  Even though such words are often written "cooperation" and  "co-op" [the hyphen being necessary, in at least some contexts, to distinguish it from a dwelling for birds] I would consider the use of a diaeresis to indicate that "naïve" is two syllables to be perfectly reasonable in English.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Words like *jail*, *ail*, *fail*, *mail*, and so on, do use the combination.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: ai is typically a dipthong, which (at least) in English isn't considered two syllables. It's not pronounced the same in "bait" as it is in "naive", but fortunately English doesn't give a flying fairy about phonetic spelling, so there's no need for decoration to distinguish the different sounds of cough, bough, bought, through, though, hiccough, rough. You just learn 'em ;-)

Comment: Anyway, I don't think this question is, in the end, specific to academia. All the comments and answers seem to boil down to just whether "naive" with that spelling is or is not an admissible English word, with no reference to it being any more or less admissible in academia than any other formal writing. And of course the note that academics are courteous people who try to represent names correctly for their original language/orthography, which while true is irrelevant to the question about cases *where the underlying language is English* :-)

Comment: @supercat The diaeresis indicates the start of the next syllable, so it's "coöperation", not "cöoperation".

Comment: @hvd: Mea culpa.  Actually, the typography I've seen which I prefer would center the diaeresis between the two letters, but I don't know if there's any nice way to render that in Unicode.

Comment: Please take extended discussion to [chat].

Comment: @Anonymous your comment, if pasted as an answer, would be the only reasonable one so far.

Answer (score 18):

Do you like reading papers with misspelled words, grammar errors, uncertain syntax, badly formatted equations, unreadable graphs and unclear pictures? Probably not.

Modern typesetting systems and careful proofreading allow writers to avoid, as much as possible, the above unpleasantnesses and, moreover, allow them to typeset all sort of characters. Furthermore, macros and shortcuts can be defined for quickly repeating difficult words. Thus, with modern typesetting systems there's really no excuse for not using diacritical marks, regardless of practices which date back to an epoch when typesetting systems were not as flexible as modern ones.

Academic papers and books are not only read by native English speakers, but by people from all over the world, where a missing accent can be cause of confusion or, in case of many missing accents, considered a sign of sloppiness (which typically does not put the reader in a favourable mood), especially if the accent is missing from a proper name.

Comment: This is perhaps a bit harsh with respect to words like 'naive' for which diacritical marks are not strictly necessary.

Comment: @E.P.: It's not my intention to be harsh, but I have a strong position on this. Indeed, _naive_ is just an example which, moreover, cannot be misunderstood for another term. But _cliche_ is not _cliché_: not only are they pronounced differently in French, but they also have different meanings and this can be a source of confusion. Then, if in the same paper or book, I find naive, cliche, Schrodinger and Thevenin (instead of _Thévenin_), I might wonder how much care was put into writing.

Comment: I'm perfectly in agreement with Schrodinger, Thevenin and cliche being quite jarring to read. However, certain words have been incorporated into the English language and acceptable forms include both with and without diacritics. The word [*naive*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/124881?redirectedFrom=naive#eid) is one such example, as are *premiere* and *role*. Would you expect authors to differentiate between the masculine *naïf* and the feminine *naïve* throughout?  - Just to say that there is indeed a line after which diacritics can be omitted.

Comment: This answer demonstrates a misunderstanding of how words pass from one language to another. When a word from one language is considered fully incorporated in another, it is good and proper that its spelling is modified to match the usual spelling conventions of the target language. Which, in English, is to not use diacritics. When English words are incorporated into French, the opposite occurs and diacritics are added. See, for example, *pénalty*, which in French is only used in the context of sports such as football, and thus has a different meaning from the English word *penalty*.

Comment: @fkraiem: several English dictionaries have incorporated French words with their original spellings only. Look, for instance, at _cliché_ or _à la carte_ on dictionaries like Oxford or McMillan: they recorded only the original spelling (Merriam-Webster's  reports, instead, also the alternative spellings _cliche_ and _a la carte_). So, it seems to me that what you say, though not incorrect, is not generally recognized.

Answer (score 17):

I personally always use them, mostly since my last name includes a dieresis, but most style guides only tell you to be consistent: either always use them, or never use them. Like Chris pointed out in his comment: consistency means consistency for each word. There have been some answers that point out that names should always be spelled with whatever accents marks the person uses. To do otherwise would be disrespectful. For other words it's up to you.

Comment: This normally means consistent for a given class of words though - and I would say the common classes in increasing order of importance of preserving accents are: *Words commonly used in English (e.g. "naive")* ; *Foreign words used within a discipline (can't think of an accented example off the top of my head)*; *Proper names (e.g. Möbius)*.  Even more important is to be consistent per word.

Comment: @ChrisH True. I'll add that to my answer :) Most of the example from my discipline that have accents come from proper names, like Turán graphs.

Answer (score 13):

You should follow the conventions of the style guide for the journal/publisher you're writing for.  A general pattern is that words which have been fully borrowed and assimilated into English  as ordinary vocabulary (such as "naive") tend to lose their diacritics, whereas words or phrases that are still considered foreign, flowery, or restricted to specialized use (e.g., détente, fin de siècle) tend to keep them.  The place where you would most likely keep them is in proper nouns (especially names of people).

Comment: Essentially, if your editor spells and pronounces *hôtel* the French way, then you'll be spelling it *naïve*.

Comment: Exception: *café*, definitely fully naturalized in English, but nonetheless tends to keep its diacritic, possibly because it has a noticeable effect on the pronunciation.

Answer (score 4):

Not having enough reputation for comments, I'll add my perspective on the topic with an answer.

There are words that have more than one accepted usage, such as naive/naïve or a la carte/à la carte, where accepted means these are actually alternative spellings and are shown in dictionaries. [Here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_words_with_diacritics) is a list of English words with diacritics; some of these words have alternative spellings.

However, while in some languages it may be acceptable to replace diacritics by a version without, such as the German *ö* replaced by *oe*, in other languages certain funny looking characters are not considered diacritics. An example that comes to mind is Finnish, where *ä* and *ö* are considered two vowels that also have their place in the alphabet, and not a version of *a* and *o* on steroids. As such and as stated [here](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/lang/finnish-letters.html), "*replacing them by ae and oe is not acceptable for Finnish*".

So my view on the subject is to use them unless you're unable to; and I can't see why you would be [unable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter) to do so nowadays. I don't mind *naive* because it is still correct (and a widely used alternative spelling); *Jyvaeskylae* instead of *Jyväskylä* on the other hand, would just tell me you either do not know the correct spelling or are plain lazy.

Comment: As it's been pointed out in comments `a la carte` has a different meaning because `a` is a verb. It is sometimes cited as an alternative form, I just find it lazy, that accent being represented on all English keyboards.

Comment: @njzk2 What is the different meaning _in English_? "a" is not a verb in English.

Comment: @cpast: `"a" is not a verb in English`, that's not really relevant since the locution is not English but French. `a` is a verb form and `à` is a preposition. Using one for the other changes the signification. `a la carte` means `(he) has the card/menu` which makes little sense.

Comment: @njzk2: _"As it's been pointed out in comments `a la carte` has a different meaning because `a` is a verb."_ -- [Some](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/a%20la%20carte) dictionaries mention the alternative, [others](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/a-la-carte) do not. Personally I prefer to use the diacritics. Some that are not displayed on the keyboard can still be used such as the umlaut which for me is <kbd>Right-Alt + ´</kbd>. Others not available as a shortcut or which I do not know are copied over; I find it doable since it only happens so much.

Comment: @njzk2 "à la carte" originated in French, but that doesn't mean its appearances in English text are snippets of French. The phrase has become part of English, and can evolve independently of its French origin (e.g. losing diacritical marks), which is perfectly valid language evolution.

Comment: @cpast: I can agree to most of that. The loosing of the diacritic can be indeed seen as an evolution and integration in the English language. I tend to see it as laziness (but then again, that is a valid reason to change the spelling)

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to answer is what purpose the accent serves.  Traditionally, in English and related languages, the accents have three purposes: to change pronunciation (for instance, the cedilla in the word soupçon causes the c to be pronounced like an s, not a k), to distinguish between homophones (as in French, between a, which means "have", and à, which means "at"), and to mark a change in historical spelling (the circumflex often indicates an s that has been lost to history, as in the French word hôpital, which used to be hospital).

My answer would be that an accent that shows a change in pronunciation (especially acute accents and diaereses) should be retained in formal writing, because we cannot know who will read it, and the reader may need these pronunciation aids; the same argument could be made for homophone distinctions, particularly in poetry.

However, if the accent marks a spelling change, it would depend on when the change occurred: there is no reason to continue to mark a spelling change that occurred before the word entered the English language.  If the accent exists, for instance, on the French word, like contrôle, and it shows a letter was omitted long before the word was borrowed into English, then there is no reason to continue to mark the missing letter that was never part of the English spelling.  There is, for instance, no mention on Oxford Dictionaries on-line of the spelling hôtel in English.  The older word hostel came into the language in the middle ages, and is still spelled thus.  The newer form hotel arrived in the mid-seventeenth century, when its French form was already spelled with a circumflex, and the two words were used differently.  Hence, it is pointless to write hôtel; these are two separate words, not a change to an older form in English.

On the other hard, there are some newer conventions that are equally acceptable.  The older spelling coöperate had already been completely lost by the time I learned to spell, twenty-five years ago, having been replaced by co-operate, which seems to do the same job, and so is perfectly reasonable.  These days, cooperate seems to be quite common, and of course, there are no language police to say that it ought not be so; however, in formal writing, I still use the hyphen (as in e-mail; remember when there was still a hyphen there?  And that was an originally English word!  **And yes, it is okay to begin a sentence with the word "and"; your English teacher only said no because all young school children do it far to much).

Comment: I think _do it far **to** much_ was intentional. However, _On the other **hard**_ was a typo. I hope I am right.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very hard to be consistent with the two dots, for example if you use it in naïve, you should probably use in coöperate, reënter, etc.

The diaeresis forbids to join in speech sounds of two vowels - it gives a hint to the reader not to read cooperate as in *Cooper*, or reenter as in *reel*

Sometimes we see them separated explicitly co-operation, re-enter, but since naive, cooperation, and reenter are very common, special orthographic rules may apply.

I would write:

- naive
- cooperate or co-operate
- re-enter

Comment: "The diaeresis forbids to join in speech sounds of two vowels" This depends on the language. It is true in French, not in German for example. Moreover, of your examples, only *naïve* has an explicit diaeresis in French, *coopérer* is written as in English, and *réentrer* takes an accent on the first letter. Overall, I can't think of a single french word where there would be a *tréma* to separate two identical vowels.

Comment: There is another difference between your examples: *naive* is the only one to be directly taken from French, so adding the diacritic is only a matter of keeping the original spelling. Imo it is the same as *café* vs. *cafe*: both spellings correct, and consistency with the rest of the english language is not really an issue.

Comment: @T.Verron _"This depends on the language. It is true in French, not in German for example."_ The question is about English, so I think we should assume that the answers are also about English unless otherwise mentioned.

Comment: @JiK I agree, but in the english language, accents only exist on foreign words (afaik, after all, English is not my native language). The examples in the question and comments include *naive* and *Schrodinger*, which is why I wanted to point out that this answer does not address the latter.

Comment: @T.Verron: Actually, it is just as true in German, because strictly speaking, a *diaeresis* is (as expressed by the word *diaeresis*) *always* about separating the pronunciation of two characters. In German, it only appears in a few names such as *Piëch*. German *umlauts* happen to use the same diacritic mark (two dots above the letter) as what is used for a diaeresis, but in spoken language, an *umlaut* and a *diaeresis* are two conceptually different things that just happen to have the same textual representation.